# Share sheet Cancel buttons invisible swift

Tags: cancel-button, ios-sharesheet

Is anyone else running into this problem. I recently noticed that the cancel/save buttons on the share sheets are now white making them impossible to read.

I've tried changing the navigation bar color but that doesn't even seem to work so clearly I'm missing something else.

This still works properly on devices running IOS 10 but having issues with devices running IOS 11

[messanger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD3G2.jpg)

[Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFGYT.png)

[Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPGhE.png)

[Twitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAVF5.png)

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into similar issues. It seems like title text attributes set on UINavigationBar get passed down to the UIActivityViewController from iOS 11 on.

So something like this:

```
let barButtonItemTextAttributes = ...
let barButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self])
barButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes(barButtonItemTextAttributes, for: UIControlState())
```

... affects the sharing sheets as well. In my case, the `foregroundColor` attribute was set to `.clear` to disable Back button labels on the navigation bar, but it also removed the above mentioned cancel/save buttons.

Maybe this applies to your case as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The problem is that when I change the color of the barButtonText, it also changes the color of the "back" button in that view controller from white to lets say blue.